# why is 1 appended to the input layer of a neural network?

Tags: neural-network

I am following this tutorial for making neural network
https://www.kaggle.com/antmarakis/another-neural-network-from-scratch

I do not understand the train part of this code where 1 is appended to the input feature vector.

```
def Train(X, Y, lr, weights):`
    `layers = len(weights)`
    `for i in range(len(X)):`
        `x, y = X[i], Y[i]`
        `x = np.matrix(np.append(1, x)) # Augment feature vector`
        `activations = ForwardPropagation(x, weights, layers)`
        `weights = BackPropagation(y, activations, weights, layers)`
    `return weights
```

any help in understanding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward propagation includes multiplying by weights and adding a bias term. The equation is

`y = X*W + b`. This can be written in a more vectorised form as `y = [X, 1] * [W, b]`. (`*` stands for matrix multiplication here).

In the code, the weights and biases seemed to have been combined into a single weight matrix `W` and `x` is modified as an augmented vector by appending a one to it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, So, In case I check the weight matrix, does the first column represent the bias weights then, or is it the last?